# Socket.io: Namespace & WS protocol

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, namespaces

#### Step 1: server

I've created a simple server with Node & [Socket.io](http://socket.io) which declares a namespace under `/my-namespace`. Once somebody connects, emit a confirmation msg as `CONNECT_ACK` and emit 3 seconds later another event (for example `SOME_EVENT`) with a payload:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

let app = express();
let server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server listening on port 3000');
  let io = new socketIO(server);
  io.of('/my-namespace').on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('welcome!');
    socket.emit('CONNECT_ACK');
    setTimeout(() => {
      io.of('/my-namespace').emit('SOME_EVENT', { a: 4 });
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```

#### Step 2: client

Then, I created the smallest client side which just connects to the namespace and logs when it receives `CONNECT_ACK` or `SOME_EVENT`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>example</title>
  <script src="./node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    const endPoint = "http://localhost:3000/my-namespace";
    io(endPoint)
      .on('CONNECT_ACK', () => { console.log("I've connected"); })
      .on('SOME_EVENT', (data) => { console.dir(data); });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Step 3: Checking everything is awesome

Running the client `node index.js` and serving the html (I use Python Simple Server) I got the desired in both consoles:

[image: client side]

[image]

#### Step 4. Understanding whats going on here

Now, when I opened the `Network` Chrome tab I started writing this long post. These are the requests:

1. **[WebSocket Protocol]**: GET to **`/socket.io`** (not to **`/my-channel`**) receiving some confirmation bits; POST again to `/socket.io` including those confirmation bits. OK.
2. **[I don't get this]**: again a GET to `/socket.io` including the confirmation bits which now resolves to the `CONNECT_ACK` event: `ÿ40ÿ40/my-namespaceÿ42/my-namespace,["CONNECT_ACK"]`. This is the only event I'm going to receive this way.
3. **[WS]**: A GET to `/socket.io` indicating it's a websoket returns me a 101 (Switching Protocols) and I can recieve the msgs as: `42/my-namespace,["SOME_EVENT",{"a":4}]`
   which is the event I send from the server & some `2`s or `3`s periodically
4. **[I don't get this too]**: again a GET to `/socket.io` including the confirmation bits which now resolves to this thing: `ÿ6`

---

- Why does the client asks for `socket.io` instead of `/my-channel`?
- Why there is a GET **after** the WS handshake which receives `CONNECT_ACK` msg?
- I understand that the "inmortal" request which resolves in 101 is the socket itself, and those `2`s and `3`s are just periodical checks.
- Why does all the events start by `42` (I've checked this does not change)
- What is that final GET? is it part of the WS protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the client asks for `socket.io` instead of `/my-channel`?

When setting up `socket.io-server`, socket.io will set itself to intercept any request to `/socket.io` in order to work.  Namespaces use the same notation as paths in HTTP, but mean completely different things, and connecting to a namespace performs the same HTTP request to `/socket.io`, but with a different namespace argument in it.

> Why there is a GET after the WS handshake which receives CONNECT_ACK msg?

I can't be sure of this one, but this probably arrived to the server *before* the WS request, and sent the `CONNECT_ACK` via polling instead.

> Why does all the events start by 42 (I've checked this does not change)

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol/issues/11), it defines the packet as a `message` (`4`) of type `event` (`2`).  Personally, I suspect the `4` is actually the protocol version, currently `4`, as it's the only reference to that number in the docs except in packet types (which must then be `2`).

> What is that final GET? is it part of the WS protocol?

Not sure again, but *possibly* a confirmation that the WS connection has been established and a way for socket.io to confirm that it should switch from polling to WS and start sending the events there.